# regex doesn't match in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I'm going to extract the name and the id of some scraped data using this script:

```
if ( $string =~ m/(;r=\d*.*<)/ ) {

    $mystring = $1;
    $mystring =~ s/;//;

    if ( $mystring =~ m/(>.*<)/ ) {

        $mystring = $1;
        $mystring =~ s/>//;
        $mystring =~ s/<//;

        print "$mystring \n";
    }
}
```

in which `$string` contains one line of the input file per iteration. Here are some lines:

```
<pre>
<option data-url="/nav/extra/list?s=prix_asc&amp;cat=436&amp;npk=1&amp;b=4294959199&amp;r=4294959195" >ZAN 3713</option>
<option data-url="/nav/extra/list?s=prix_asc&amp;cat=436&amp;npk=1&amp;b=4294959199&amp;r=4294959194" >ZAN2310</option>
<option data-url="/nav/extra/list?s=prix_asc&amp;cat=436&amp;npk=1&amp;b=4294959199&amp;r=4294959193" >ZAN2410</option>
```

What I expect normally is `;r=4294959193" >ZAN2410<` as the result; but the problem is that Perl doesn't detect any matches! 
Is there any problem with my regex?

Comment: If you have a full HTML document you should use an HTML parser instead of regular expressions.

Comment: @simbabque You're right but as a question, I want to know what's the problem.

Comment: I think it might be too greedy, but I would have to see how you read the file and what `$string` contains. You can add [`use re 'debug'`](https://metacpan.org/pod/re#debug-mode) to the top of your code to see what the regex engine is doing. That might give you a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there probably are. But honestly, I'd probably tackle it a bit differently. Use an HTML parser is the first port of call.

Like for example - you're re-using `$mystring`, and that's usually a warning sign that you're not using `strict` and `warnings`, and thus are doing things that you're not expecting.

You're not getting the output you desire, because you overwrite `$mystring` with this bit, for example:

```
    if($mystring =~ m/(>.*<)/){
        $mystring = $1;
```

But having run your code with your sample data - it seems to almost work - because you're clobbering `$mystring` you're getting:

```
ZAN 3713 
ZAN2310 
ZAN2410
```

I would suggest a slightly different approach though:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    m/r=(\d+)\"\s*>([^<]+)/g && print "$1 $2\n";
}

__DATA__
<pre>
<option data-url="/nav/extra/list?s=prix_asc&amp;cat=436&amp;npk=1&amp;b=4294959199&amp;r=4294959195" >ZAN 3713</option>
<option data-url="/nav/extra/list?s=prix_asc&amp;cat=436&amp;npk=1&amp;b=4294959199&amp;r=4294959194" >ZAN2310</option>
<option data-url="/nav/extra/list?s=prix_asc&amp;cat=436&amp;npk=1&amp;b=4294959199&amp;r=4294959193" >ZAN2410</option>
```

This gives you output of:

```
4294959195 ZAN 3713
4294959194 ZAN2310
4294959193 ZAN2410
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sobrique. I could resolve the problem thanks to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to do what you're asking. The values of (the first) `$mystring` evaluate to

```
;r=4294959195" >ZAN 3713<
;r=4294959194" >ZAN2310<
;r=4294959193" >ZAN2410<
```

the last of which matches your expected string `;r=4294959193" >ZAN2410<`

But then you go on to extract the value between `>` and `<` and print that, which gives

```
ZAN 3713 
ZAN2310 
ZAN2410
```

Which again is what I would expect, so I don't see any issue here. To get the result you say you want you should just omit the inner `if` block altogether